# Unable to drop column with foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, foreign-keys, key, alter-table

I created a table using `Entityframework` in `ASP.NET`. My database is `MySQL`. I ran a `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command on my MySQL and I got the following result.

```
'AttendancePercentageDetails', 'CREATE TABLE `AttendancePercentageDetails` (\n  `AttendancePercentageDetailsId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,\n  `Percentage` double NOT NULL,\n  `SiteDetailsID` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  `UserDetailsID` int(11) NOT NULL,\n  PRIMARY KEY (`AttendancePercentageDetailsId`),\n  KEY `IX_SiteDetailsID` (`SiteDetailsID`) USING HASH,\n  KEY `IX_UserDetailsID` (`UserDetailsID`) USING HASH,\n  CONSTRAINT `FK_AttendancePercentageDetails_UserDetails_UserDetailsID` FOREIGN KEY (`UserDetailsID`) REFERENCES `UserDetails` (`UserDetailsID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,\n  CONSTRAINT `FK_AttendancePercentageDetails_SiteDetails_SiteDetailsID` FOREIGN KEY (`SiteDetailsID`) REFERENCES `SiteDetails` (`SiteDetailsId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE\n) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=812 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

I am trying to drop the `foreign key` `UserDetailsID` by using the following commands.

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
ALTER TABLE dbclockit.AttendancePercentageDetails DROP FOREIGN KEY UserDetailsID;
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

MySQL throws an error saying

```
Error Code: 1091. Can't DROP 'UserDetailsID'; check that column/key exists
```

I ran

```
SELECT * FROM dbclockit.AttendancePercentageDetails;
```

and the output has the `UserDetailsID` column.

Answer (score 1):

This worked.

```
ALTER TABLE dbclockit.AttendancePercentageDetails DROP foreign key FK_AttendancePercentageDetails_UserDetails_UserDetailsID;
ALTER TABLE dbclockit.AttendancePercentageDetails DROP COLUMN  UserDetailsID;
```